# Error Run Tensorflow Example Android

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow

I,am run Tensorflow Example Android and i get error :

Error:Execution failed for task ':buildNativeBazel'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/usr/local/bin/bazel''

how do i solve this problem

Thanks before ....

Answer (score 1):

you should install NDK and rebuild your project . 
for install NDk go to this Page and Download that https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html

Later than install NDK go to the file -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> Android NDK Location: -> enter NDK Location

Comment: i think you should try this answer again :/